# Оптимизировать вложенные циклы

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы

Есть два листа:

```
List<String> firstList ;
List<String> secondList;
```

Передо мной стоит задача найти похожие строки,то есть сравнить каждую строку из первого листа с каждой строкой из второго,строки считаются похожими если одна строка содержит другую без учета окончания. За это у меня отвечает отдельный метод.

На ум сразу приходит сделать цикл в цикле и просто перебирать строки одну за другой ,но есть сомнения. Можно ли решить эту задачу без вложенных циклов или в данном случае без двух циклов не обойтись? Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

**ПРАВКА 1**

Код снизу корректно сравнивает объекты,но почему-то пропускает некоторые значения

```
public void resolve() {
        String firstWord = null;
        String secondWord = null;

        List<String> firstGroup = reader.getFirstGroupContent();
        List<String> secondGroup = reader.getSecondGroupContent();

       
        for (int i = 0; i < firstGroup.size(); i++) {

            firstWord = firstGroup.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < secondGroup.size(); j++) {
                secondWord = secondGroup.get(j);

                if (areStringsSimilar(firstWord,secondWord)){
                    resultingPairs.put(firstWord,secondWord);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean areStringsSimilar(String firstString, String secondString) {

        String firstStringWithoutEnding = firstString.substring(0, firstString.length() - 1);
        String secondStringWithoutEnding = secondString.substring(0, secondString.length() - 1);

        if (firstStringWithoutEnding.contains(secondStringWithoutEnding)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: без учета окончания какой строки первой или последней? Можно попробовать отсортировать оба листа. И внутренний цикл проходить не до конца, а если видим, что уже дальше точно не будет похожей строки, "брейкаться"

Comment: @had0uken без учета окончаний обоих строк

Comment: вместо contains в данном случае нужно использовать startsWith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по условию задачи, в любом случае нужно делать два цикла, т.к. нужно сравнить все строки каждая с каждой.
Ваш код пропускает значения, потому что вы ищете вхождение второй строки в первую. А надо ещё обработать ситуацию вхождения первой строки во вторую.

```
    private boolean areStringsSimilar(String firstString, String secondString) {

        if (firstStringWithoutEnding.contains(secondStringWithoutEnding)) {
            return true;
        }
// надо добавить
        if (secondStringWithoutEnding.contains(firstStringWithoutEnding)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Ну или другой вариант - находите длины строк и ищете вхождение меньшей сторки в большую.

Также правильно написал @Эникейщик - по условию задачи строки должны начинаться одинаково, т.е. 1 строка - `aaabbbccc` 2 строка - `aaa` - тогда эти строки похожи. И не надо их уменьшать. Используйте `startsWith()`

```
private boolean areStringsSimilar(String firstString, String secondString) {

        if ( secondString.startsWith( firstString ) ) return true;
        if ( firstString.startsWith( secondString ) ) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю,вторая проверка спасла ситуацию